# Changing default shell to our own written shell in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a basic shell in linux and also implimented few basic commands such as pwd and chmod.

I want to set my created shell (executable) as a default shell whenever terminal opens. I tried chsh -s shellname, unfortunately it done nothing .echo $SHELL still gives /bin/bash as a current shell.I also edited /etc/shells file and added my shell in last.

Please Help..

Comment: Did you use absolute path for `shellname`? I wonder if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The login shell of a user account is defined inside the unfamous `/etc/passwd` file. Just use a plain text editor and change it (e.g. `joe /etc/passwd`):

This is a typical example entry:

```
john:x:1000:100:John Doe:/home/john:/bin/bash
```

At the end you can see the absolute path of the executable configured as the accounts login shell. Just change it point to your custom shell.

Note that this changes the *login shell*. So to see the effect you have to relogin, not just to open a new terminal. So either test it by connecting to localhost using ssh for example or logout/login to your graphical desktop.

Comment: Thanx it worked, i was just opening the new terminal but relogin worked.

Comment: @Mzzl Why should you have to update the shadow file in this case?

Comment: @Mzzl May I suggest _not_ to call `/etc/passwd` the "password" file? The name is miss leading.

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/newshell username
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is changing the /etc/passwd as @arkascha explained.
You need root and be sure your script works.
An alternative is adding your script at the end of your login script $HOME/.profile
When you're done and give exit (or ctrl-d), you will return in your default shell.
You can give other commands or give exit again.
Adding exit at the end of your .profile will prevent the second exit.
Not sure you want to exit? Put sleep 2 before the last exit, ctrl-c will be possible.

I do not know why you created a new shellscript, when it is only for practice you might want a temporary solution in .profile.